# WordPress "Loading mixed (insecure) display content on a secure page"

Tags: php, html, wordpress, https, mixed-content

I'm pretty new to web development. I developed this [website](https://veritaneuro.com/) using WordPress.
It works fine and it has a SSL certificate as well.

On the [homepage](https://veritaneuro.com/), I can see the secure icon (lock icon) in the URL box but when I navigate to the [about us page](https://veritaneuro.com/about-us/), I get the following error message in the console and I don't get to see the secure icon in the URL box

```
Loading mixed (insecure) display content “http://52.76.129.235/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/uam-footer.jpg” on a secure page
```

I tried to debug the error. These are the things I did:

1. Used a plugin called Better Search Replace to replace http to https
2. Manually changed all values that had http in database to https
3. Added `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);` to `wp-config.php` in WordPress root folder

Can anyone tell me how to fix this error? I tried to locate the URL given in the error message, but I didn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, it is super easy just you need to follow some steps.

1. Install and Activate the [Really Simple SSL](https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl) plugin.
2. After activation, a notice will appear at the top with a button saying **Go Ahead, Activate SSL**, click on the button to do so.
3. Now, go to **Settings > SSL** and enable the **WordPress 301 redirect** in the toggle.

That's it for simple. You can also buy the *Really Simple SSL Pro* if you need additional configuration.

Don't hesitate to contact me for further response. I hope the method worked for you.